# Mass import of Mobile Push preference data

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

We are moving away from a third party notification service to Marketing Cloud's Mobile Push. We hold preference data (customer, status and device ids) from our old system. Can this be migrated to Mobile Push?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Import into the Marketing Cloud MobilePush**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_mp_import_contacts_to_a_standard_list_or_into_all_contacts.htm&type=5):

Additional attributes can be created on the MobilePush Demographics attribute group in data designer.

> You can also include custom information required to send messages by adding attributes for your contacts. You can’t query or export the information in a system table. The system table contains these [**attributes**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_mp_contacts.htm&type=5)